# Selecting all except one element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am making a javascript effect which goes like:
it will have a couple of images. when the user hovers over the current image all the other images fadeout but the image that the mouse is over stays the same.
kinda like opposite to "this" keyword.

like: suppose the following are three images

[image]

if the user takes his mouse over the '2' img then all the other (1 and 3) should fadeout but '2' should remain the same.

http://74.53.198.125/~elven/ameer/csstemplate/

Comment: Can you show the markup and javascript that you're using? Be terse. Only include the relevant parts.

Comment: be more specific.. onmouseout.. what should happen then? should all images appear again?

Comment: jQuery is included in the page linked to at the end of your post, did you mean to include the jQuery tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a:not(:hover)')
```

If I get the question right. This if your framework is supporting :hover in selector engine (jQuery does, for example). Otherwise, you can bind on hover event and mimic it.

Comment: there is no jquery tag in here ;)

Comment: @Walialu, no, actually you approach does have sense. But if you want to be really pure, you should implement fadeout effect as well :) If one mentions fadeout or anything else animated, he is likely using some framework. Nevertheless it does not mean that this frameworks supports hover)

Comment: yea, that was my point, so i was leaving the fading part - but I could not guess which framework.. so was doing it plain vanilla js style :)

Comment: thanks man... i did not knew about :not(:hover)... that works beautifully

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$('img').hover(function(){
    $('img:not(:hover)').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give all the images the same class and use `.each()` function to fade all of them and unfade just the one that has the mouse over

```
$('.imgClass').mouseover(function(){

        $(".imgClass").each(function(){

            $(this).fadeOut();

        })

        $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

When the mouse is out

```
     $(".abcd").mouseout(function(){

            $(".abcd").each(function(){

                $(this).fadeIn();

            })



          })
```

Comment: @Ameer: Have a look at the Edited answer....also added the code to show all images when the mouse is out...

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving the fading part ;)

```
var foo = function(a,where){
  var length = where.getElementsByTagName('img').length;
  for(var i=0; i<length;i++){
    var img = where.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];
    if(img != a){ // all images except the hovered image
      img.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{ // the hovered one
      img.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

style.display.. is no fading.. that part is up to you ;)

use it like this

```
<img src="...." onmouseover="foo(this,document.getElementById('divContainerForAllMyImages'));" />
```